# URL Path using MySQL and PHP

Tags: php, mysql, url, path

I am trying to display my database entries as a single page. Here an entry in the database should be the path. I imagine it as follows:

Database:
Entry 1 (content of the web page): My Content
Entry 2 (Path): test

Path:
https://example.com/test

I have found many ways to display a path as follows:
https://example.com/view?id=test

However, I do not want to do that. Can someone please help me!
Thank you very much.

Comment: You would need to use url rewriting (Apache or Nginx) and redirect requests to a single file.
Frameworks like Laravel work exactly this way, depending on your project I would recommend learning it.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any code available for my purpose?

Comment: Are you using Apache or Nginx?

Comment: See what it is and search for url rewrite.
But basically you use a regexp to validate the input url and if the conditions are met it will redirect to the file you inform.

Comment: I'm really everything but a pro. I think Apache